# c++ How to copy vector of struct into another vector of struct with kind of duplication

Tags: c++, vector, struct

How to copy vector of struct into another vector of struct such as:

Let the first, and second vectors as:

```
std::vector <myStruct> OriginalVector 
std::vector <myStruct> NewVector
```

where:

```
struct Linkedvalues{
    int indx;
    double Val;
};

struct myStruct{
    std::vector<int> Id;
    double avg;
    std::vector<Linkedvalues> lValues;
    double sum= 0.0;
};
```

in my program, I filled `OriginalVector` and i need to copy its values in `NewVector` with this duplication:

let `OriginalVector` has the following values:

```
{ (1, 2), 0.6, {(1, 0.5), (3,0.1), (5,0.7)}, 1.5 } 
{ (1, 3), 0.5, {(1, 0.2), (4,0.9), (5,0.7)}, 3.1 } 
{ (2, 3), 0.1, {(3, 0.4), (2,0.2), (5,0.7)}, 4.2 } 
{ (3, 5), 0.3, {(2, 0.1), (3,0.6), (5,0.7)}, 7.5 }
```

I want to create `NewVector` as:

```
{ (1, 2), 0.6, {(1, 0.5), (3,0.1), (5,0.7)}, 1.5 } 
{ (2, 1), 0.6, {(1, 0.5), (3,0.1), (5,0.7)}, 1.5 } // also add the same previous 
                                                   //vector but swap (1,2) to (2,1)  

{ (1, 3), 0.5, {(1, 0.2), (4,0.9), (5,0.7)}, 3.1 } 
{ (3, 1), 0.5, {(1, 0.2), (4,0.9), (5,0.7)}, 3.1 }  // also add the same previous 
                                                   //vector but swap (1,3) to (3,1)

{ (2, 3), 0.1, {(3, 0.4), (2,0.2), (5,0.7)}, 4.2 } 
{ (3, 2), 0.1, {(3, 0.4), (2,0.2), (5,0.7)}, 4.2 } //also add the same previous 
                                                   //vector but swap (2,3) to (3,2)

{ (3, 5), 0.3, {(2, 0.1), (3,0.6), (5,0.7)}, 7.5 } 
{ (5, 3), 0.3, {(2, 0.1), (3,0.6), (5,0.7)}, 7.5 }  //also add the same previous 
                                                   //vector but swap (3,5) to (5,3)
```

In order to do that, I did the following:

```
int i=0;
while (i < OriginalVector.size())
{
 auto it = (std::make_pair(OriginalVector[i].id.front(), OriginalVector[i].id.back()));
 auto itt = (std::make_pair(OriginalVector[i].id.back(), OriginalVector[i].id.front()));

// Here I fail to insert it and itt with the rest of OriginalVector[i] members into NewVector 
++i;
}
```

Comment: Well, there's no `pair<T, U>` in those structures at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: But `vector` of size 2 is not a pair. That's just not the way type system works. You're probably looking for something like `vector<int>(OriginalVector[i].id.front(), OriginalVector[i].id.back())`

Comment: If that first vector really always stores exactly two elements, you should seriously consider making it a `std::pair`, `std::tuple` or `std::array`. Much more efficient.

Comment: Yes, there is no `pair<T, U>` in my struct, but in previous processing, I deleted all `id` in `OriginalVector` of size < 2.

Comment: Were those with `Id.size() != 2` in any way important? If not, why read them at all? Or could you read thm in a separate data-structure instead, and make this one more specialized?

Comment: Yes I need them, because i have large data, and with all Id.size() = 1 and have some thresholds i create Id.size() = 2. after that i delete all  Id.size() = 1. thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector <myStruct> NewVector;
NewVector.reserve(OriginalVector.size() * 2);
for (auto&& v : OriginalVector) {
    NewVector.push_back(v);
    NewVector.push_back(v);
    auto& x = NewVector.back().Id;
    std::swap(x[0], x[1]);
}
```

That's the quick fix.

There's no reason to create the new elements first, and then push them after.